# Integrating Google Wallet in PHP web application

Tags: php, api, object, android-pay

I am trying to run a sample PHP web application integrated with Google Wallet. Similar to this: http://iap-php.appspot.com.

I have been following the documentation provided in https://developers.google.com/wallet/objects/quickstart-php#register. I created a project. And I couldn't get **Wallet Object API** in the list.
And I am stuck here:

[image]

And on clicking "sign up for Wallet Objects API access", I have filled the form and got a mail from Google that:

> We are reviewing your information and will update you via email on your eligibility and next steps soon.

And I am unable to continue further.

Basically I wanted to run this integration with PHP on my localhost for testing purpose. How do I setup wallet objects? What docs I have to read? From where do I have to start?

Comment: The message from Google is fairly self-explanatory, isn't it? It looks like they manually review registrations, and you will get an email from them.

Comment: Wasn't the Google Wallet API going to be retired soon? Don't know if they will take new registrations.

Comment: This is not a technical question

Comment: @albhilazo Google Wallet for digital goods will be retired on 3/2/2015.  i dont think its the API.

Comment: @halfer i am not sure , if everyone is following these steps... but i want to test it.